# Pyspark write fails on overwrite mode in bigquery database

Tags: pyspark

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryConnectorException$InvalidSchemaException: Destination table's schema is not compatible with dataframe's schema

```
df.write \
.format('bigquery') \
.option('table', (project + '.db.tbl')) \
.mode("overwrite") \
.save()
```

Comment: I think the error is kind of self-explanatory. The schema of the dataframe doesn't mathc the schema of the table you're trying to write to. It could be a mismatch between numerical data types (integer vs decimal, etc), or it could be a StringType column violating the character limit its destination column in the landing table

Comment: Thanks for your observation , Its quite different , I have dropped the table schema and re-executed . IThe script executed without any  error and also the table created successfully. 
If we are executing Second time with the same script without any modification then we are facing this problem

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the schema validation checks became much stricter on June 1st 2022. I suspect there was an update to the dataproc image. We're using 2.0.29-debian10.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the latest version of BQ spark connector (0.25.0) : https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/releases

Fix your version to the previous version (0.24.2) and you will not have this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation since 1st jully 2022, it seems like you should not use the latest versions as recommended in google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example) :

> For **non-production** use, you can also point to the latest jars, as follows:
> Dataproc image version 1.5 and above: --jars=gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark->bigquery-latest_2.12.jar

I was working with the latest version and as soon as i changed the spark-biquery version to : gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.23.2.jar -> It worked just fine.

Edit: For more information about the upgrade (schema equality) see [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/pull/613/files).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and when I upgraded to an even newer version, the problem went away.

The failing version:
gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.25.0.jar

The working version:
gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.27.0.jar